# What does this crash report mean?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, debugging, crash-log

I am getting this crash log from my release build but have a hard time figuring out what this means.

Is this UIKit crashing because the label got removed from superview while it was being animated?

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x000000000000defe
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   UIKit                           0x36011c7e -[UIView release] + 54
1   UIKit                           0x3603d12c -[UIView dealloc] + 292
2   TestApp                         0x0011fb0e -[ValueLabel .cxx_destruct] (ValueLabel.m:47)
3   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3beeff26 object_cxxDestructFromClass(objc_object*, objc_class*) + 54
4   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3beed0de objc_destructInstance + 30
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3beed3ae object_dispose + 10
6   UIKit                           0x3603d2e2 -[UIView dealloc] + 730
7   TestApp                         0x0011fa48 -[ValueLabel dealloc] (ValueLabel.m:306)
8   libsystem_blocks.dylib          0x3c32bab0 _Block_release + 220
9   UIKit                           0x360255e0 -[UIViewAnimationBlockDelegate dealloc] + 56
10  CoreFoundation                  0x341406da CFRelease + 98
11  CoreFoundation                  0x34161d78 -[__NSDictionaryI dealloc] + 128
12  libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3beed490 (anonymous namespace)::AutoreleasePoolPage::pop(void*) + 164
13  CoreFoundation                  0x3414282c _CFAutoreleasePoolPop + 12
14  CoreFoundation                  0x341d31b2 __CFRunLoopRun + 1290
15  CoreFoundation                  0x34146238 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 352
16  CoreFoundation                  0x341460c4 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100
17  GraphicsServices                0x37d24336 GSEventRunModal + 70
18  UIKit                           0x360622b4 UIApplicationMain + 1116
19  TestApp                         0x000e6cae main (main.m:16)
20  TestApp                         0x000e6c64 start + 36
```

Comment: You over-released something methinks. Try enabling zombies.

Comment: you overreleased a view in object_cxxDestructFromClass(objc_object*, objc_class*)

Comment: I can't enable zombies on a release build

Comment: Also this project uses ARC. All I do is animate views and remove them from superview

Answer (score 3):

If you are removing views instantiated in Storyboard or NIBs, make sure the IBOutlet properties are **strong** or **retain** rather than **weak** or **assign**, otherwise they will be released as soon as they are removed from the parent view.

This is

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel* labelToRemove;
```

rather than

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel* labelToRemove;
```